# SocketTimeoutException when testing on Android Studio simulator

Tags: android-studio, chat

When I attempt to connect through a socket to my Android App, I get the following error:

> 10-02 01: 32: 30.295 1738-1892 / me.schat E / schat / SimpleSocket: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to schat.me/188.40.116.82 (port 7667) after 20000ms

This error occurs only in the emulator. When i test directly on the phone it works.
Internet works on the emulator, the browser opens any website.

My socket code in its entirety

```
package me.schat.net;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.util.Log;

import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class SimpleSocket {
  private static final String TAG = "schat/SimpleSocket";
  private final Object m_sendLock = new Object();

  private boolean m_authorized = false;  // true после успешной авторизации.
  private DataInputStream m_in;          // Поток чтения транспортных пакетов.
  private DataOutputStream m_out;        // Поток записи транспортных пакетов.
  private Handler m_handler;             // Объект доступа к потоку отправки пакетов.
  private int m_reconnects = 0;          // Число попыток восстановить соединение.
  private long m_rxSequence = 0;         // Счётчик полученных пакетов.
  private long m_txSequence = 0;         // Счётчик отправленных пакетов.
  private Network network;               // Информация для подключения.
  private PacketListener m_packets;      // Слушатель пакетов.
  private Socket m_socket;               // Сокет подключения.
  private SocketListener m_listener;     // Слушатель сокета.
  private Thread m_thread;               // Поток чтения пакетов.
  private Timer m_timer;                 // Таймер обслуживающий соединение.
  private TimerTask m_killTask;          // Задача для отключения от сервера, если он не ответил за определённое время.
  private TransportReader m_reader;      // Объект чтения транспортных пакетов.
  private ByteArrayOutputStream m_send = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); // Поток отправки пакетов.


  public SimpleSocket(SocketListener listener, PacketListener packets) {
    m_listener = listener;
    m_packets = packets;
    m_reader = new TransportReader(this);
    m_timer = new Timer("SocketTimer");

    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("simplesocket-thread");
    thread.start();
    m_handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
  }


  public boolean connect(Network network) {
    this.network = network;
    return connect();
  }


  public boolean connect() {
    Log.d(TAG, "connect()");

    if ((m_thread != null && m_thread.isAlive()) || network == null)
      return false;

    m_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG, "RUN " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

        int port = network.uri.getPort();
        if (port == -1)
          port = Protocol.DEFAULT_PORT;

        try {
          SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(network.uri.getHost(), port);
          SocketFactory factory = SocketFactory.getDefault();

          m_socket = factory.createSocket();
          m_socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
          m_socket.setKeepAlive(true);
          m_socket.connect(sockaddr, Protocol.CONNECT_TIMEOUT);

          m_in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(m_socket.getInputStream()));
          m_out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(m_socket.getOutputStream()));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
          Log.e(TAG, ioe.toString());
          reconnect();
          return;
        }
        catch (NullPointerException npe) {
          Log.e(TAG, npe.toString());
          reconnect();
          return;
        }

        ping();
        m_reconnects = 0;
        m_listener.onConnect();
        m_listener.onAuthRequired();

        try {
          m_reader.start(m_in);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Socket read exception", ioe);
          reconnect();
        }
      }
    });

    m_thread.start();
    return true;
  }


  public boolean send(final WritablePacket packet) {
    List<WritablePacket> packets = new ArrayList<WritablePacket>();
    packets.add(packet);

    return send(packets);
  }


  public boolean send(final List<WritablePacket> packets) {
    if (packets.isEmpty())
      return false;

    m_handler.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        synchronized (m_sendLock) {
          try {
            List<byte[]> raws = new ArrayList<byte[]>(packets.size());
            int options       = Protocol.NO_OPTIONS;

            for (WritablePacket packet : packets) {
              final byte[] raw = packet.write(m_send).toByteArray();
              raws.add(raw);

              if (raw.length > 65535)
                options = Protocol.HUGE_PACKETS;
            }

            new TransportWriter(m_out, raws, m_txSequence, options);
            m_txSequence++;
          } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Send failed", ioe);
          }
        }
      }
    });

    return true;
  }


  public final Network getNetwork() {
    return network;
  }


  public final PacketListener packets() {
    return m_packets;
  }


  public final synchronized boolean isAuthorized() {
    return m_authorized;
  }


  public final synchronized void setAuthorized(boolean authorized) {
    m_authorized = authorized;
  }


  public final void leave() {
    m_reconnects = -1;
    disconnect();
  }


  /**
   * Отключение от сервера.
   */
  public final void disconnect() {
    if (m_socket == null)
      return;

    m_handler.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          if (m_socket != null) {
            m_socket.close();
            m_socket = null;
          }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Error while disconnecting", ioe);
        }

        if (m_thread != null) {
          m_thread.interrupt();
          m_thread = null;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  public final void ping() {
    if (m_killTask != null)
      m_killTask.cancel();

    m_timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
        if (isAuthorized()) {
          transmit(new byte[0], Protocol.INTERNAL_PACKET);

          m_killTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
              disconnect();
            }
          };

          m_timer.schedule(m_killTask, Protocol.REPLY_TIMEOUT);
        } else
          disconnect();
      }
    }, Protocol.IDLE_TIMEOUT);
  }


  private void reconnect() {
    if (m_thread != null) {
      m_thread.interrupt();
      m_thread = null;
    }

    if (m_reconnects == -1)
      return;

    if (m_reconnects >= Protocol.MAX_FAST_RECONNECTS + Protocol.MAX_NORMAL_RECONNECTS)
      m_reconnects = 0;

    ++m_reconnects;

    m_timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
        connect();
      }
    }, m_reconnects <= Protocol.MAX_FAST_RECONNECTS ? Protocol.FAST_RECONNECT_TIME : Protocol.NORMAL_RECONNECT_TIME);

    m_listener.onReconnect();
  }


  private boolean transmit(final byte[] packet, final int options) {
    List<byte[]> packets = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    packets.add(packet);
    return transmit(packets, options);
  }


  private boolean transmit(final List<byte[]> packets, final int options) {
//    Log.d(TAG, "transmit(List<byte[]> packets)");

    if (packets.isEmpty())
      return false;

    m_handler.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        synchronized (m_sendLock) {
          try {
            new TransportWriter(m_out, packets, m_txSequence, options);
            if (options != Protocol.INTERNAL_PACKET)
              m_txSequence++;
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    });

    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question or the problem?

Comment: why an error? please help